# Try Failure is not catching exceptions

Tags: scala

In the code below I have two Play for Scala functions, the first one catches an exception (this works fine) and in the second one I'm trying to rewrite it using `Try`.

I have two problems with `Try`: (1) when the number is negative the method doesn't fail, (2) I need to wrap all the responses with `Future.successful`.

How to fix this code?

```
  class Test extends Controller  {

    def test1 = Action.async { request =>

         val future = isPositive(-1)
         future.map { result =>
             Ok("OK, it's positive")
         }
         .recover { 
             case e => Ok(e.getMessage)
         }
    }

    def isPositive(i: Int) = Future {
        if (i<0)
            throw new Exception ( "Number is negative" )
        else
            i
    }

    def test2 = Action.async { request =>
        isPositiveWithTry(-1) match {
            case Success(s) => Future.successful(Ok("OK, it's positive (Try succeded)"))
            case Failure(f) => Future.successful(Ok(f.getMessage + " (Try failed)"))
        }
    }

    def isPositiveWithTry(i: Int) : Try[Future[Int]] = Try {
         isPositive(i)
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `isPositive` method exceptions are already caught by `Future`

```
def isPositive(i: Int) = Future {
        if (i<0)
            throw new Exception ( "Number is negative" )
        else
            i
}
```

In the below code

```
def isPositiveWithTry(i: Int) : Try[Future[Int]] = Try {
     isPositive(i)
}
```

`isPositive` already catches all expections and `Try` is always a `success`.

So, when `i` is negative. Exception raised are handled by future and try gets a success value, resultant Try is a success. So you get successful Try with a failed Future inside.

## Understanding using Grenade example

Assume throwing the exception as blowing up a Grenade.

Assume `Future` and `Try` as two layers. When grenade is blasted inside the double layer of `Try[Future]` i.e Try is around Future and grenade is gone off in the Future.

Now `Future` withstands the blast and becomes a failed value. As Future already took the damage caused by the damage of exception(grenade). Try will be a success but the value inside the Try is a failed future value. That failed future value is nothing but the exception raised.

## Try is redundant when you are using Future

You can refactor your code to below one

Get rid of `isPositiveWithTry`. This method is not needed.

```
 def isPositive(i: Int) = Future {
    if (i<0)
        throw new Exception ( "Number is negative" )
    else
        i
 }

def test2 = Action.async { request =>
    isPositive(-1).flatMap { _ =>
       Future.successful(Ok("OK, it's positive (Try succeded)"))
    }.recoverWith {
        case f: Throwable => Future.successful(Ok(f.getMessage + " (Try failed)"))
    }
}
```

Again `test2` can also be written as

```
 def test2 = Action.async { request =>
    isPositive(-1).map { _ =>
       Ok("OK, it's positive (Try succeded)")
    }.recover {
        case f: Throwable => Ok(f.getMessage + " (Try failed)")
    }
 }
```

In case `isPositive` returns `Try`

```
def isPositive(i: Int) = Try {
        if (i<0)
            throw new Exception ( "Number is negative" )
        else
            i
}
```

Now `test2` will look like

```
def test2 = Action.async { request =>
        isPositive(-1) match {
            case Success(s) => Future.successful(Ok("OK, it's positive (Try succeded)"))
            case Failure(f) => Future.successful(Ok(f.getMessage + " (Try failed)"))
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand how to use `Try` instead of catch/try. What would your answer be if instead of returning a Future in `isPositive` you return `Try[Int]` ?

Comment: @ps0604 added more info to the answer. Please check

Comment: Thanks. One last question: is it bad practice to throw exceptions in Scala? Otherwise, how do you return errors to another class?

Comment: @ps0604 yes, it is bad to throw exceptions in functional programming. Instead, exception cases have to be communicated using values. But in some special exceptions can be thrown. Also sometimes methods of Scala and also those inherited from Java throw exceptions. So, its better to contain them using Try etc. Finally "Exceptions can be thrown in some special cases. "

Answer (score 1):

Couple points:

1) You need to rewrite your `isPositive` such that it does not surround itself via a `Future`. The `Future` is catching the exception.

```
def isPositive(i: Int) ={
  if (i<0)
    throw new Exception ( "Number is negative" )
  else
    i
}
```

2) If you have a `Try` and you want a `Future`, then you can use the method on the companion object of `Future`, `Future.fromTry`. That will take a `Try` and turn it into the correct state of a `Future`.